# * Couldn't match type `(Float, Float)' with `[Point]'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**CODE**

```
type Point = (Float,Float)
type Candidate = (Point,Point,[Point],Float)


print_list :: [[Point]] -> String
print_list [] = ""
print_list [x:xs] = show x ++ "," ++  print_list(xs)

candidate_to_string :: Candidate -> String 
candidate_to_string (a, x, y:ys, z) = "Start point: " ++ show a ++ 
"\nSupporting Points: " ++  print_list(y:ys) ++ "\nEnd Point: " ++ show x 
++ "\nTime: " ++ show z
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
C:\\Users\conor\Desktop\haskellcoursework.hs:47:50: error:
    * Couldn't match type `(Float, Float)' with `[Point]'
      Expected type: [[Point]]
        Actual type: [Point]
    * In the first argument of `print_list', namely `(xs)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely `print_list (xs)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely `"," ++ print_list (xs)'
   |
47 | print_list [x:xs] = show x ++ "," ++  print_list(xs)
   |                                                  ^^

C:\\Users\conor\Desktop\haskellcoursework.hs:50:107: error:
    * Couldn't match type `(Float, Float)' with `[Point]'
      Expected type: [[Point]]
        Actual type: [Point]
    * In the first argument of `print_list', namely `(y : ys)'
      In the first argument of `(++)', namely `print_list (y : ys)'
      In the second argument of `(++)', namely
        `print_list (y : ys)
           ++ "\nEnd Point: " ++ show x ++ "\nTime: " ++ show z'
   |
50 | candidate_to_string (a, x, y:ys, z) = "Start point: " ++ show a ++ 
"\nSupporting Points: " ++  print_list(y:ys) ++ "\nEnd Point: " ++ show x ++ 
"\nTime: " ++ show z                   ^^^^
   |
```

The signatures I have used are specified for me. My task is to write a function candidate_to_string :: Candidate -> String which creates a string representation
of a candidate. Each Point is written in its own line starting with the start point, followed by
all supporting points and ending with the end point. The time is printed in an extra line consisting
of the string “Time: ” and the value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do not post code as an image, other users do not want to transcribe your code in order to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_list` requires a `[[Point]]` -- a list of lists of points

```
print_list :: [[Point]] -> String
           -- ^^^^^^^^^ --
```

but here you pass it a `[Point]` a list of points. Hence, a type error arises:

```
candidate_to_string :: Candidate -> String 
candidate_to_string (a, x, y:ys, z) = 
    ...  print_list(y:ys) ...
                -- ^^^^^^ this is a [Point]
```

The mistake is that `print_list` should instead be `[Point] -> String`. More in detail,

```
print_list [x:xs] = show x ++ "," ++  print_list(xs)
```

is wrong, since `[x:xs]` is a list containing only one element, namely the list `x:xs`. You don't want a list-of-lists here, so simply use something like

```
print_list :: [Point] -> String
print_list []     = ""
print_list [x]    = show x   -- we don't want a trailing comma here
print_list (x:xs) = show x ++ "," ++  print_list xs
```